# Set AutocorrectionTypeDefault = YES for a whole application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I've read that we can set autocorrection like

`textField.autocorrectionType = YES;`

for one textField.
But how to set this property for whole application?

Thank in advance!

Comment: `UITextInputTraits.autocorrectionType` is not a boolean value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple create your own Customclass and set the property in the constructor.

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@end


@implementation CustomTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

if your create a new Textfield, create the object with your custom class:

```
CustomTextField *field = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame: ...];
```

Comment: Oh interesting I never knew you could do something like this. +1

Comment: Thanx to you, Meccan, it was alternative idea